# Is there a way to "truncate a row"?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to be able to clear all data in a row so that I still have the row with the primary key, but all other fields become their default value. Is there a simple command to do this in SQL or do I have to query the schema and loop through the columns manually?

I happen to be using sqlite3 and knex.

Comment: well, this operation is a bit weird. Anyways, resetting the data to default value/empty in a row is a quick UPDATE operation. You shouldn't worry so much.

Comment: For completeness' sake, do you mind providing a bit more context on what gives rise to your requirement in which you won't know the schema of your own database beforehand?

Comment: @esqew I'm writing an api based on the http actions of POST, PATCH, PUT, etc. This is supposed to simulate PUT.

Comment: If you think this is a generic SQL question, then use just the SQL tag instead of tag spamming with every DBMS tag you can find.

Comment: The operation you're referring to isn't a standard kind of operation, so there's no shortcuts. I would recommend an update statement as per @dmg below. Otherwise I thought of recommending the REPLACE sql statement, which is a delete and insert combined together. You might want to look into it and see if it can answer your need, sqlite should support it from what I read. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: @WadihM. Thanks! I actually think REPLACE is what I'm looking for - I'm just surprised that the behavior is to delete the whole row and create another one, creating a new auto increment id. Nevertheless I think this is most similar to a built in version of http's PUT, which is really what I was looking for. The posted answer is hard coding it which I was trying to avoid, but technically it is a more accurate answer to my question since I specified to keep the primary key value. So I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest I can think of is:

you can replace NULL with whatever value the default for the attribute is.

```
UPDATE R set att2= NULL, att3 = NULL, att4 = NULL, <etc> ;
```